# Loading views into region in wpf

Tags: wpf, region

Let me make the question simple. I have created two prism regions. first region has a button. On click of this button I want to load a view in the second region. How do I do this? Ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are referencing Regions of Prism?

The [View-Switching Navigation QuickStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430881%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) demonstrates how to use the Prism Region Navigation API. The QuickStart simulates the navigation of a simple email, contacts, and calendar application. The left region provides navigation to each of the main views. The views demonstrate backward navigation and asynchronous dialog interactions.